# How to read data from dynamic cell ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dynamic

How to get the Dynamic tableview cell data. 
[image: Dynamic page]
I have a table view like this. All the cells are creating dynamically. 
I want to get all the text (flavor and %)data when submit button is pressed. 
The problem was I creating text in dynamically. So I cannot individually identify the text box. How could get the data from dynamic text box?

Comment: where you creating textbox ? in `cellForRowAtIndexpath`?

Comment: logic of you are use text filed delegate method and store string after button click that use. text filed method write cell file.

Comment: Show your code.  How you dynamically load data in Table.

Comment: yes creating textbox in cellForRowAtIndexPath. #ketan

Comment: then set `tag` to that `textfields` and you can get that `textfields` on submit button click by it's `tag` as i shown in my answer!

Comment: while adding the textfield to cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, then add it to an array, then you can access the array of textFields and its properties

Answer (score 1):

You can set `tag` to your `textfield` and by that tag you can access them.

For example,

```
  UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30)];

textField.tag = 100;  //set tag

UITextField *textField1 = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:100]; //retreive by tag
```

So, like this you can manage your dynamically made `textfields`.

**Update :**

then set two tag 100 and 101 respectively. Now you have to got cell first and from that cell you can got your `textfields` so on button's click first got all cell, then you can got `textfield` from that cell like :

```
  UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
```

So, you have to got cell first in your button's click.

Comment: In this cause. all the flavour textbox get tag as 100.
So how to get the value in submitbuttonPresed function.

Comment: set different tag to every textield!!!!!  you can set `indexPath.row` as tag also for unique identification!

Comment: do you have four textfield in one cell or one textfield per one cell ??

Comment: I have two text fields( Flavor and % -in image) in one cell.
I am reusing that cell.

Answer (score 1):

Set tag to your uitextfield in your custom cell

```
For eg.

cell.lblFlavour.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.lblPercent.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Now, access your uitextfield on the basis of your indexPath

Answer (score 1):

Use `tag` property to identify each `UI` component uniquely. Assign the same `tag` property where you are creating `textFields` and `button` to each row then after change `tag` value for next row and get them using code.

**To set `tag`:**

```
self.yourTextfield.tag = 100;
self.yourbutton.tag = 100;

// set action method to uibutton 
[cell.yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**To get the `UI` components using `tag` property:**

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    // here get all ui component using tag 
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"%d", [button tag]);
}
```

or you can use method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to get values see code:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"getting index path %@",indexPath);

    NSLog(@"getting index path %@",cell.yourTextField.text);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main idea of `UITableView` is store data into **data source**, not into **cell**. When you tap "+" button on the navigation bar, you should add new item into array and then call `[tableView reloadData]`. So a `UITableView` just represent data from array. And when submit button will pressed you just enumerate an array of data source and get all the text from each row.

When you tap text into text field inside the cell, you could use `delegates` or `blocks` to store data into array.

Answer (score 0):

try below code :

When you click on submit button

```
  for (int i=0; i < [[tableView visibleCells] count]; i++)
{
  //yourArrayname is the number of rows in the UITableView /Or UITableView visible cells

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: i   inSection: 0];

            CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tblExperience cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                    for (UIView *view in  cell.contentView.subviews){

                    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){

                    UITextField* CurrentTextField = (UITextField *)view;
                NSLog(@"val %d  %@",i,CurrentTextField.text);

                [finalArray addObject:CurrentTextField.text];
                }
     }
     }
```

Comment: I tried this code. But the app stack in this code. This take more memory and execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Assign dynamic tags to your textfields, implement textfield delegates and save the data in an array whenever textfield ends editing. Something like this

```c
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField { 
    [_array insertObject:textField.text atIndex:textField.tag];
}
```